# How can I set limitation of output images size from PDF files using GhostScript

Tags: image, pdf, ghostscript

Now I'm trying to convert a PDF File to a Image file.

I hope to get a image file from a PDF file using GhostScript.
The output image should be 500x500 size.
It means whole size of the image is resized to fit 500x500 size.

I am already tried options below.
No special option : Output image is crop to 500x500 size....
-dFitPage : It automatically rotate image. The long side is to be changed to Height.
other -*FitPage options are same....

What I want is same with using -dFitPage without rotation.

Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: The only option you have mentioned is '-dFitPage', you must be doing more than that as it will have no effect at all with a PDF file unless you are also setting a fixed media size. If you don't like the way that FitPage works, then you can of course rewrite it not to allow rotation. The relevant code is for 'PDFFitPage' in pdf_main.ps, especially in pdfshowpage_setup (around line 2225). Alternatively you can write a custom setpagedevice handler to spot media requests, remove them, but scale the content to fit.

Comment: Thanks you!
I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is not possible by using ghostscript but you can make it works by using custom bitmap like i did

```
 var outputPNGPath = Path.Combine(outputFolder, string.Format("{0}.jpeg", filename));
                var pdf2PNG = rasterizer.GetPage(xDpi, yDpi, i);
                Bitmap resized = new Bitmap(pdf2PNG, new Size(1240, 1754));
                resized.Save(outputPNGPath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                pdf2PNG.Dispose();
                resized.Dispose();
```

this is worked for me to convert 1240*1654 image to 1240*1754